# I'm having trouble creating a Kotlin database adapter

Tags: database, kotlin, adapter

I'm trying to build a room database app with Kotlin. Database part is ok. I need to create adapter to show database data in Recyclerview. But I can't use the holder command. I think it might be related to "Kotlinx.Synthetic has been deprecated". I want to introduce textviews id's to adapter. When i try "holder.itemView.id_txt.text = currentItem.id.toString()" it does not recognize "id_txt.text". Can you help with  introduce the custom row's textview ids to adapter. Thank you.

[image]

User.kt

```
import androidx.room.Entity
import androidx.room.PrimaryKey

@Entity(tableName = "user_table")
data class User(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    val id: Int,
    val firstName: String,
    val lastName: String,
    val age: String
)
```

UserDao.kt

```
import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData
import androidx.room.Dao
import androidx.room.Insert
import androidx.room.OnConflictStrategy
import androidx.room.Query

@Dao
interface UserDao {

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    suspend fun addUser(user: User)

    @Query("SELECT * FROM user_table ORDER BY id ASC")
    fun readAllData(): LiveData<List<User>>

}
```

UserDatabase.kt

```
import android.content.Context
import androidx.room.Database
import androidx.room.Room
import androidx.room.RoomDatabase

@Database(entities = [User::class], version = 1, exportSchema = false)
abstract class UserDatabase : RoomDatabase() {

    abstract fun userDao(): UserDao

    companion object {
        @Volatile
        private var INSTANCE: UserDatabase? = null

        fun getDatabase(context: Context): UserDatabase{
            val tempInstance = INSTANCE
            if(tempInstance != null){
                return tempInstance
            }
            synchronized(this){
                val instance = Room.databaseBuilder(
                    context.applicationContext,
                    UserDatabase::class.java,
                    "user_database"
                ).build()
                INSTANCE = instance
                return instance
            }
        }
    }

}
```

UserRepository.kt

```
import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData

class UserRepository(private val userDao: UserDao) {

    val readAllData: LiveData<List<User>> = userDao.readAllData()

    suspend fun addUser(user: User){
        userDao.addUser(user)
    }

}
```

UserViewModel.kt

```
import android.app.Application
import androidx.lifecycle.AndroidViewModel
import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData
import androidx.lifecycle.viewModelScope
import kotlinx.coroutines.Dispatchers
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch

class UserViewModel(application: Application): AndroidViewModel(application) {

    private val readAllData: LiveData<List<User>>
    private val repository: UserRepository

    init {
        val userDao = UserDatabase.getDatabase(application).userDao()
        repository = UserRepository(userDao)
        readAllData = repository.readAllData
    }

    fun addUser(user: User){
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            repository.addUser(user)
        }
    }

}
```

AddFragment.kt

```
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider
import androidx.navigation.fragment.findNavController
import com.example.basehw.R
import com.example.basehw.data.UserViewModel
import com.example.basehw.databinding.FragmentAddBinding

import android.text.TextUtils
import android.widget.Toast
import com.example.basehw.data.User




class AddFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var mUserViewModel: UserViewModel

    private var _binding: FragmentAddBinding? = null
    private val binding get() = _binding!!


    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        _binding = FragmentAddBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)


        mUserViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(UserViewModel::class.java)

        binding.addBtn.setOnClickListener{

            insertDataToDatabase()
        }

        return binding.root
    }

    private fun insertDataToDatabase() {

        val firstName = binding.addFirstNameEt.text.toString()
        val lastName = binding.addFirstNameEt.text.toString()
        val age = binding.addAgeEt.text.toString()

        if(inputCheck(firstName, lastName, age)){
            // Create User Object
            val user = User(
                0,
                firstName,
                lastName,
                age
            )
            // Add Data to Database
            mUserViewModel.addUser(user)
            Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "Successfully added!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            // Navigate Back
            findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_addFragment_to_listFragment)
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "Please fill out all fields.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
    }


    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
    }


    private fun inputCheck(firstName: String, lastName: String, age: String): Boolean{
        return !(TextUtils.isEmpty(firstName) && TextUtils.isEmpty(lastName) && age.isEmpty())
    }

}
```

ListFragment.kt

```
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.navigation.fragment.findNavController
import com.example.basehw.R
import com.example.basehw.databinding.FragmentListBinding


class ListFragment : Fragment() {

    private var _binding: FragmentListBinding? = null
    private val binding get() = _binding!!

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        _binding = FragmentListBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)

        binding.floatingActionButton.setOnClickListener{

            findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_listFragment_to_addFragment)
        }

        return binding.root
    }


    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
    }

}
```

ListAdapter.kt

```
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import androidx.viewpager2.adapter.FragmentViewHolder
import com.example.basehw.R
import com.example.basehw.data.User
import com.example.basehw.databinding.ActivityMainBinding
import com.example.basehw.databinding.FragmentListBinding

class ListAdapter: RecyclerView.Adapter<ListAdapter.MyViewHolder>() {


    private var binding: ActivityMainBinding? = null


    private var userList = emptyList<User>()

    class MyViewHolder(itemView: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {}

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder {
        return MyViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.custom_row, parent, false))
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return userList.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val currentItem = userList[position]

        holder.itemView.id_txt.text = currentItem.id.toString()
        holder.itemView.firstName_txt.text = currentItem.firstName
        holder.itemView.lastName_txt.text = currentItem.lastName
        holder.itemView.age_txt.text = currentItem.age.toString()


    }

    fun setData(user: List<User>){
        this.userList = user
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
}
```

custom_row.xml

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/custom_row"
    android:padding="24sp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/id_txt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/_1"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/firstName_txt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="80dp"
        android:text="@string/john"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/id_txt"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lastName_txt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:text="@string/dao"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/firstName_txt"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/age_txt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:text="@string/_25"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/lastName_txt"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

fragment_list.xml

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".fragments.list.ListFragment">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
        android:layout_width="409dp"
        android:layout_height="729dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/floatingActionButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:tint="@color/white"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        tools:ignore="SpeakableTextPresentCheck" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

As **Kotlinx.Synthetics** has been deprecated, you should use **view binding** which you are already using in your fragment and activity, you should also use it in your **RecyclerView adapter**.

Make a few changes in your recycler view adapter to work with view bindings.

```
class ListAdapter: RecyclerView.Adapter<ListAdapter.MyViewHolder>() {


    private var userList = emptyList<User>()

    class MyViewHolder(private val customRowBinding: CustomRowBinding): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(customRowBinding.root) {
        fun bind(user: User) {
                customRowBinding.idTxt.text = user.id.toString()
                customRowBinding.firstNameTxt.text = user.firstName
                customRowBinding.lastNameTxt.text = user.lastName
                customRowBinding.ageTxt.text = user.age.toString()
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder {
        return MyViewHolder(CustomRowBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false))
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return userList.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val currentItem = userList[position]
        holder.bind(currentItem)
    }

    fun setData(user: List<User>){
        this.userList = user
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
}
```

Instead of binding data inside `onBindViewHolder`, create a `bind()` method inside the view holder and bind there.